# Image button event in datalist not working

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, datalist

the image button events are not firing am i missing something from my code
      the on itemcommand event doesn't trigger please help me i'm stucked in it
this is my datalist code:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="100%"
    onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="comments_pannel_top">
    <h2>Highly Recommended,</h2>
    <p>By:<a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server"></asp:Label></a> – 
        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"></asp:Label>, 
        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"></asp:Label> <span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="stars_1">
    <img src="images/favourities_icon.jpg" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
    <img src="images/favourities_icon.jpg" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
    <img src="images/favourities_icon.jpg" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
    <img src="images/favourities_icon.jpg" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
    <img src="images/favourities_icon.jpg" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
    <p><strong>5 out of 11 people found this review helpful.</strong></p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblReview" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="report_abuse">
    <p>Did you find this review helpful?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="comments_pannel_bottom">
    <div class="btns">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnYes" ImageUrl="images/yes_btn.jpg" width="33"   height="23"  runat="server" CommandName="Yes" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNo" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/no_btn.jpg" width="33" height="23" alt="" CommandName="No"/>

    </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

  This is the onitem command event handler:

  protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server-side event handler are they bound to?  Usually the markup contains an `OnCommand` property which binds the command event to a server-side handler.  See examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandname.aspx):

```
<asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton2" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Edit"
       ImageUrl="images/pict2.jpg"
       OnCommand="ImageButton_Command"
       CommandName="Edit"/>
```

The value for the `OnCommand` property would be the name of the server-side event handler method:

```
void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
   //...
}
```