# DataList with button linked to a method (Vb.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This my data list:

```
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
               RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <ItemTemplate>
                Titre:
                <asp:Label ID="TitreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Titre") %>' />
                <br />
                Description:
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Handler.ashx?ID={0}") %>' Width="200" Height="200"/>

                <br />
                comments:
                <asp:Label ID="commentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comments") %>' />
                <br />

                Ajouter commentaire 
                <asp:button ID="btnAjouter"  runat="server" Text="Ajouter" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

In the Vb.aspx code I create a method:

```
public Sub updateComments()
.......
End Sub
```

And I want to add an event to my DataList button and excute the method.

I don't know how to do it correctly.

This is in Vb.net.

Thanks

Frank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790016/image-button-event-in-datalist-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx) to your button and handle the DataList's [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand.aspx).

For example(in ItemTemplate)

```
<asp:button ID="btnAjouter" CommandName="Ajouter"  runat="server" Text="Ajouter" />
```

In Codebehind:

```
Sub Item_Command(sender As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs)Handles DataList1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Ajouter"
        '  do something '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also note you can add a parameter to work with using the `CommandArgument` Property of the `Button` and access in `Item_Command` via `e.CommandArgument`.  +1 :)